# okay a very common problem is the number of arrangements of letters such that no two vowel letters are adjacent

Tags: combinatorics

what i want to know how the solution to this problem makes the answer valid how we are sure that every time we choose using ncr the vowels will not be adjacent okay i will provide a problem with solution to illustrate more 
if we have a word permutation
find the Permutations of string such that no two vowels are adjacent
the constants are 6 
the vowels are 5
the solution is the following   (6! / 2!) * (7C5 * 5!)
the first part is the constant part i understand that very well the second part why we give that the remaining places should be equal to 7 places 
this the link to the problem thanks in advance
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutations-of-string-such-that-no-two-vowels-are-adjacent/

Comment: "An arrangement of letters such that no two **letters** are adjacent"  I can only think of the one-letter words satisfying this.  Surely you have written a word incorrectly here somewhere.

Comment: two vowels are adjacent my mistake sorry

Comment: At the right of the key M you have some signs like commas and periods.

Comment: So... your question appears to be "why seven places?" when arranging the vowels.  Suppose we have arranged the consonants first.  Place little gaps to the left and right of each like so:  $\underline{~~}P\underline{~~}R\underline{~~}M\underline{~~}T\underline{~~}T\underline{~~}N\underline{~~}$.  Notice that there is one more gap than the number of consonants used since we are allowing to the far left or to the far right.  Now, pick which of those gaps is used and pick which vowel occupied each space.

Comment: so the number of places is the number of vowels plus two as we fix the constants first okay i got it thanks a lot is there's a way of solving the problem by computing all the possible adjacent vowels ? and then exclude it from the answer ?

Comment: No.  It is just a fluke that the number of available spaces for vowels is two more than the number of vowels.  What is important is that the number of available spaces is one more than the number of consonants.  If the word being arranged was `prmttions` instead where we have only two vowels rather than five, it would still be seven places.  As for your second part of your comment, yes... we *could* technically try to apply inclusion-exclusion and remove the "bad" arrangements where there were at least one occurrence of a vowel next to another, but this is much more difficult and tedious to do

Comment: This seems to be a very common problem, indeed.

Comment: yes i got it thanks a lot we also to check if (const+1<vowels) we will always out put zero as there we can't compute ncr thanks a lot i got it

Comment: @JMoravitz please copy your comment and paste it so i can say the problem is solved

Comment: That cannot be done to a question which has been closed.